# WMI SQLSERVERAGENT_SQLAgentJobs queries don't return data on some SQL 2016 Availability Group instances

Tags: wmi, sql-agent

The SQL Server Agent has [performance objects and counters](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190382.aspx) for monitoring jobs. Using the Windows Performance Monitor application I can always see the data:

[image: perfmon]

But when I try using `gwmi Win32_PerfFormattedData_SQLSERVERAGENT_SQLAgentJobs` in PowerShell on some servers there are no instances returned. Same results when testing with WBEMTest and wmic.exe.

When I run `typeperf -qx` I see a bunch of \SQLAgent:Jobs(_Total)* metrics, but how can I use a WMI query to get results from the `Win32_PerfFormattedData_SQLSERVERAGENT_SQLAgentJobs` or `Win32_PerfRawData_SQLSERVERAGENT_SQLAgentJobs` classes?

**UPDATE:** hmm... this may just be an issue when querying a SQL Server 2016 CU1 or SP1 CU2 Availability Group instance, although again it works on some servers but not others. Seems to stop working after applying updates, and even after restarting the system the counters don't return any instances. I have not yet been able to replicate the issue on a standalone instance, as they always return the expected data:

```
PS C:\> gwmi Win32_PerfRawData_SQLSERVERAGENT_SQLAgentJobs | ft -AutoSize Name,Successfuljobs,FailedJobs,Activejobs

Name      Successfuljobs FailedJobs Activejobs
----      -------------- ---------- ----------
Others                 0          0          0
Alerts                 0          0          0
Schedules             20        106          0
_Total                20        106          0
```

Also side note these counters are not available in the [sys.dm_os_performance_counters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187743.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a 2nd restart of the server the WMI queries appear to be working now. I believe that the CU and SP updates can include changes to the WMI provider, which doesn't get updated until the system is restarted. The updates sometimes say that they do not require a reboot, but if WMI queries stop working after the update then restarting the server may fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem can be related to remote user authorization and Powershell authorization on that servers.

Check if you're logging using the same default SQL_AGENT user, and check if that user has the Authorization Level required, as defined in Windows Policies and/or SQL Security Policies.

Good luck.

Comment: Interesting... I'll have to see if anything changed there.

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty straightforward based on the tutorial [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/getting-started/cookbooks/getting-wmi-objects--get-wmiobject-)

Basically, if you want to query using Powershell to get those specific WMI classes, you want to query them like this:

"If you already know the name of a WMI class, you can use it to get information immediately. For example, one of the WMI classes commonly used for retrieving information about a computer is Win32_OperatingSystem.

```
PS> Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Namespace root/cimv2 -ComputerName .

SystemDirectory : C:\WINDOWS\system32
Organization    : Global Network Solutions
BuildNumber     : 2600
RegisteredUser  : Oliver W. Jones
SerialNumber    : 12345-678-9012345-67890
Version         : 5.1.2600
```

Although we are showing all of the parameters, the command can be expressed in a more succinct way. The ComputerName parameter is not necessary when connecting to the local system. We show it to demonstrate the most general case and remind you about the parameter. The Namespace defaults to root/cimv2, and can be omitted as well. Finally, most cmdlets allow you to omit the name of common parameters. With Get-WmiObject, if no name is specified for the first parameter, Windows PowerShell treats it as the Class parameter. This means the last command could have been issued by typing:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem
```

The Win32_OperatingSystem class has many more properties than those displayed here. You can use Get-Member to see all the properties. The properties of a WMI class are automatically available like other object properties:

```
PS> Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Namespace root/cimv2 -ComputerName . | Get-Member -MemberType Property

   TypeName: System.Management.ManagementObject#root\cimv2\Win32_OperatingSyste
m

Name                                      MemberType Definition
----                                      ---------- ----------
__CLASS                                   Property   System.String __CLASS {...
...
BootDevice                                Property   System.String BootDevic...
BuildNumber                               Property   System.String BuildNumb...
...
```

"

Furthermore on the detail retrieving:

"If you want information contained in the Win32_OperatingSystem class that is not displayed by default, you can display it by using the Format cmdlets. For example, if you want to display available memory data, type:

```
PS> Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Namespace root/cimv2 -ComputerName . | Format-Table -Property TotalVirtualMemorySize,TotalVisibleMemorySize,FreePhysicalMemory,FreeVirtualMemory,FreeSpaceInPagingFiles

TotalVirtualMemorySize TotalVisibleMem FreePhysicalMem FreeVirtualMemo FreeSpaceInPagi
                              ory              ry         ngFiles
--------------- --------------- --------------- --------------- ---------------
        2097024          785904          305808         2056724         1558232
```

Note

Wildcards work with property names in Format-Table, so the final pipeline element can be reduced to Format-Table -Property TotalV*,Free*
The memory data might be more readable if you format it as a list by typing:

```
PS> Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Namespace root/cimv2 -ComputerName . | Format-List TotalVirtualMemorySize,TotalVisibleMemorySize,FreePhysicalMemory,FreeVirtualMemory,FreeSpaceInPagingFiles

TotalVirtualMemorySize : 2097024
TotalVisibleMemorySize : 785904
FreePhysicalMemory     : 301876
FreeVirtualMemory      : 2056724
FreeSpaceInPagingFiles : 1556644
```

"

Comment: The question wasn't how to do a WMI query, but why there are no results.